# How to fetch data from a JSON file?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In work on a project I use Next.js. How can I get data from a JSON file (`mainMenu`) and display it on the screen? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, props }) {
  const newProps = Object.entries(props)
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <>
      <Header />

      <div className="container">
        <nav className={styles.navbar}>
          <div className={styles.navbarInner}>
            <ul className={styles.navbarList}>
              {newProps.map((item) =>
                item.map((elem) => (
                  <li className={styles.navbarListItem}>
                    <Link href={`/${elem.url}`}>
                      <a className={styles.navbarListLink}>{elem.label}</a>
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                ))
              )}
            </ul>
            <Input />
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${url}/global`)
  console.group(res)
  return { props: res.data }
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Thank you for getting the res.data.mainMenu do I need to fix it? I am trying to get mainMen.label, mainMenu.url

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass `res.data.mainMenu` instead of `res.data` in `getInitialProps`.
2. `Object.entries` and nested `map`s are not required as `mainMenu` is an array.

Final Code:

```js
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps, mainMenu }) => (
  <>
    <Header />

    <div className="container">
      <nav className={styles.navbar}>
        <div className={styles.navbarInner}>
          <ul className={styles.navbarList}>
            {mainMenu.map(elem => (
              <li className={styles.navbarListItem}>
                <Link href={`/${elem.url}`}>
                  <a className={styles.navbarListLink}>{elem.label}</a>
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <Input />
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
)

MyApp.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${url}/global`)
  return { mainMenu: res.data.mainMenu }
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: @Cracker please accept the answer by pressing the grey tick if it helped you.